# How do I scrape a site that loads data asynchronously using node.js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, web-scraping, axios, cheerio

I am trying to scrape a site using Axios to make the request and Cheerio to parse the data. The problem I have is that the site I am making a request to loads data before displaying it. This is resulting in the HTML returning "Loading..." rather than the actual data. Is there a way to configure the Axios request to wait for the data to finish loading or is there a different library I should use to make the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to check what XHR calls are being done, and do a request against that URL instead, since the content you want is not coming from the *main* URL, but from other API calls.

But the easiest way to scrape content that's being loaded dynamically using Javascript is to use [`puppeteer`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer).

```
 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true })
 const page = await browser.newPage()
 await page.goto('https://example.com')

 await page.waitForSelector(".someSelectorThatsLoadedWithJavascript")
 // get whatever value you want now.
```

Comment: Thank you! Puppeteer does exactly what I need. Instead of using the wait for selector I passed in {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'} as the second parameter of page.goto() ----------------

await page.goto('https://example.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

Comment: Yeah, that works too, it depends on what you're scraping. Glad I could help :)